# Neo4j strange aggregation behavior

Tags: neo4j

While studying the course [Getting Started with Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-course-getting-started/),
a doubt appeared at lesson L_2_8 (Aggregation) --> (Graph LAB), section "Top-n":

Aren't the queries below equivalent? Without the "LIMIT" clause, they do return the same result.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN m.title, count(a)
ORDER BY count(a) DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Returns ...

```
The Replacements  4
Unforgiven        3
```

BUT

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN m.title, count(a)
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Returns ...

```
The Birdcage      3
Unforgiven        3
```

Without the LIMIT clause, both queries return

```
The Replacements  4
The Birdcage      3
Unforgiven        3
```

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED]

Cypher does not support `ORDER BY ColumnPosition`, like [SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html).

Therefore, I suspect that the `ORDER BY 2 DESC` clause is being ignored. I have submitted [neo4j issue #5387](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5387) to ask whether this kind of usage should be treated as an error.

Comment: Thanks! Although the results were the same in this example (without the LIMIT clause), I've verified with a larger data set that the "column numbers" in the ORDER BY clause do not work. It should be considered typo, indeed.

Comment: What do you mean by "column numbers"?

Comment: My original intention was to use _ColumnPositions_ from the RETURN clause instead of expressions, just like Oracle SQL http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html, and PostgreSql http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY.
- The ordinal number refers to the ordinal (left-to-right) position of the output column.
But it seems it is not supported by Cypher.

Comment: It treats `2` as a constant expression, ie. numeric 2 to order by, i.e. it doesn't matter.

Comment: Cypher can order by any kind of expression.